# yii dropdownlist same value for many options

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, yii

I was trying to give same value for few options in yii dropdownlist, but i get stuck.
Got something like this:

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'XXXXX', array(1=>array('XX','YY', 'XY', 'YX', 'XXX', 'YYY'),
                                               2=>array('AA','BB', 'AB', 'BA),
                                               3=>array('CD','DC', 'CC', 'DD', 'DCD', 'CDC')));
```

But it's not working (giving value 0,1,2,3,4,5 in first array :/). I want to every option with x and y to get value = 1, A and B combinations should get 2, and C&D to get value 3. How can i make it?
Hope someone can understand me ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a normal dropdownlist you have to assign a key to the individual elements of all the arrays. This key will be used as the value for the option. A key assigned to an array element, as in your code, will be used as the text/label for the optgroup.

This approach will however not work for your case because there can only be one element for each key in an array. One way is to wrap each element inside its own optgroup and use javascript to clear the labels of the optgroups after loading.

```
$form->dropDownList($model,'XXXXX', array(
    array(1=>'XX'),array(1=>'YY'),array( 1=>'XY'),....
    array(2=>'AA'),array(2=>'AB'),array( 2=>'BA'),....
    ....
    ),array('onfocus'=>'$("optgroup",$(this)).attr("label","")')
);
```

Another way you can work around this is to change the value of the attribute depending on which option has been selected.

```
public function beforeValidate(){
    if(strpos($this->XXXX,'X')!==false){
        $this->XXXX=1;
    }else ......
}
```

Comment: Thx, used 1st way to make it, but still i have numbers over every option in list :( Anyway it looks bad now, but works fine ;) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this if you are using numeric values...

Because (int)1 === (int)01 === (int)001 you can add additional leading zeros to each option. So for you...

```
echo $form->dropDownList($model,'XXXXX', array(
    '1' => 'XX',
    '01' => 'YY',
    '001' => 'XY',
    '0001' => 'YX',
    '00001' => 'XXX',
    '000001' => 'YYY',

    '2' => 'AA',
    '02' => 'BB',
    '002' => 'AB',
    '0002' => 'BA',

    '3' => 'CD',
    '03' => 'DC',
    '003' => 'CC',
    '0003' => 'DD',
    '00003' => 'DCD',
    '000003' => 'CDC'
));
```

Depending on what you're doing with your value you may then need to typecast it back to an integer, but if your Yii rules are right then that will be done anyway.

Remember that if you repopulate this dropdown from data then it will always select the only value that truly matches the value of the relevant attribute (3 = CD not DC CC etc)